# What is the English word for the tests that are made by a memory of people?

Tags: word-request

Almost at any university that I know, the students have stockpiles of tests that made by other student that already did those exams and all of the questions from exams was restored by them (I mean that they wrote the questions based on their memory because it's forbidden to picture these exams, then the only way to share it with others is by the memory...)

What is the word for that in the English students jargon? 
My friend told me that it's called "Restorations" but he's not sure about that. In my language dictionaries there is no reference for that meaning.

Comment: University *where*? As an American, I have never come across this concept.

Comment: @Catija I have never heard of the concept either. The closest thing I can relate it to is in the anime community, where people sometimes do their own *fan dubs* when no one has translated the Japanese into a certain other language. And of course in a wider community there is *fan fiction*. So maybe we can coin a word for these, **fan tests**?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a specific term, and have never heard "restorations" used for that.  They might be described as "reconstructed" from memory.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a country-specific term. Here in India, the term:

> **Question bank**

is used to refer to such a collection of questions.

Such questions might not only be compiled purely from the memory of those students who attended the tests, they may also be offered by the institution in question (for example, [here is the Question Bank](https://www.annauniv.edu/Library/gen_qbank.html) offered by [Anna University, India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_University)).

Answer (score 0):

> The questions were **recalled** by the exam participants and written down afterwards for others.

In this case  recalled = remembered.

Comment: Thank you (I didn't vote down your answer), but I don't understand it. I'm looking for **a noun** which describes these spesific tests that were recalled.

Comment: **cheating** comes to mind. Exams are owned by universities and professors, so reproducing them is a form of stealing. Peter is correct. Students recall or remember exams and reproduce them and sell them online. They also copy and distribute papers that have been marked and returned. If that is what OP wants, then I cannot help.

Comment: I mean I cannot help because I do not know...

Answer (score 0):

Many fraternities, sororities, and other student organizations maintain collections of past graded tests and homework, but there is no specific word for a test that was reconstructed from memory that I am aware of. There may be slang terms not in broad use that I don't know.